# how to insert an array value like 'hello, world" in a different row in a table in in laravel model

Tags: php, laravel

how to insert an array value like 'hello,world" in a different row in a table in php laravel model,

the word hello,world I want to insert in a table named 'test_table', and its stores in an array variable,
I want to insert the word 'hello' in first row and the word 'world' insert into the second row.

Answer (score 0):

In first : "hello,world" is a string

If you want a array variable : ["hello", "world"]

If you want transform your string into array you need to use :

> explode function => [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php)

After you have got a model who test_table is linked and normally into your controller you need follow this example :

```
$testTable = new TestTable();
$testTable->myArray = ['hello', 'world'];
$testTable->save();
```